# Intermittently getting TimeoutException while pushing to kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

**Error**:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic_name not present in metadata after 500 ms
```

We are getting this error on **production** on random intervals(quantum is very low like around 5-10 failures in a day. Around 15 events/seconds are pushed to the topic). Kafka push is getting failed here due to Timeout while fetching the **metadata** from the broker.

**Producer properties** (properties which are set explicitly, rest configs have default values):-

```
batch.size = 16384;
linger.ms = 5;
buffer.memory = 65536;
max.block.ms = 500;
```

What could be the reason behind this? Should I increase `max.block.ms = 500` Or increase the `buffer.memory`? OR some other property needs to be added to fix this issue. Also how to make sure that producer retries are working here. I read somewhere that metadata is only fetched for the first producer push, after that producer caches it in the local, Is that correct?

Comment: Is there something deleting this topic periodically? Otherwise, it sounds like a 500 ms timeout is too low for metadata request. Metadata is updated every 5 minutes, by default. Only cached in-between that, and is a different config than buffer or blocking. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#metadata-max-age-ms

Comment: There's no such job/scheduler runs which deletes this topic periodically. It stays forever once it's created. Do we have a TTL type of property on topic which deletes them periodically?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Should we increase max.block.ms here?

Comment: Topics don't have TTL, no. That setting is unrelated to your error, as mentioned. You don't need to... The default is 60000, so I'm not sure I understand why you must have it at 500. Your error is related to the timeout of the metadata request, not the record send requests, which is what all your shown configs are for

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I don't understand, are you saying that the max.block.ms does not have got to do anything with the error shown ?  max.block.ms is waiting time for both metadata fetch or to wait for the buffer to get empty right ! If that's the case than we can safely leave max.block.ms and buffer.memory on their default values right ?

Comment: 1) The default is a minute, not half a second. Why change it? So, yes, increase it, the default is **120x** your current value. 2) From the docs - _bounds the total time waiting for **both metadata fetch** and buffer allocation... For `partitionsFor()` this timeout **bounds the time spent waiting for metadata if it is unavailable**. The transaction-related methods always block, but **may timeout if the transaction coordinator could not be discovered or did not respond within the timeout**_

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Can we leave the property buffer.size as well on default value as I see default value is 33554432bytes, but we have set it 65536 bytes.

Comment: You can. That depends on your use-case for having small buffer sizes. Maybe your app is memory constrained, for example